# MIRTH: How do I send different message types (i.e. an ADT vs an ORU) coming in on a channel to two different destination files?

Tags: mirth

MIRTH: How do I send different message types coming in on a channel to two different destination files?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 things in Mirth, Filter and Transformers.

Filter is used when you have a specific requirement. It process on the input message, check for a given criteria which in this case can be your message type and route it appropriately to a file location.

Transformer on the other hand deals with the content of the message and alters it, based on your requirement. For Eg. Modifying the message type from ADT^09 to ADT^10 can be done through a transformer.
Transformer increases processing speed and has an overhead.

Based on your scenario, I would recommend using a filter against transformer. Check [here](http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/wiki/display/mirthuserguidev1r8p0/Filter+and+Mapping+Transformer)

Answer (score 2):

Configure your channel to have two destinations. Create a filter in each of the destinations that only allows the correct message type to be processed.